# Problema al crear un tercer color en javascript ( selectors-swatch)

Tags: javascript, html, css

espero me podáis ayudar, tengo configurado en JavaScript unas función para que cuando las personas hagan clic en el circulo se agrande y se vea como seleccionado al igual que cambie la imagen, que pasa cuando agrego un tercer circulo se me daña no se si lo estoy haciendo mal o me salgo algo.
aqui les dejo como funciona correctamente
https://www.babyessentials.es/roberto-verino/

JS

```
    var seleccionado="stone";

function colorSeleccionado(){
       return seleccionado;
}

function clickStone(){
    if (seleccionado=="stone"){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        seleccionado="stone";
        document.getElementsByClassName("elegance-color-label")[0].innerHTML = "Stone";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-capazo-black")[0].style.display="none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-silla-black")[0].style.display="none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-silla-stone")[0].style.display="block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-capazo-stone")[0].style.display="block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("circulo-black")[0].classList.remove("highlighted-a");
        document.getElementsByClassName("circulo-black-img")[0].classList.remove("highlighted-img");
        document.getElementsByClassName("circulo-stone")[0].classList.add("highlighted-a");
        document.getElementsByClassName("circulo-stone-img")[0].classList.add("highlighted-img");
        
                clickCheck('cochecito');

    }
}

function clickBlack(){
    if (seleccionado=="black"){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        seleccionado="black";
        document.getElementsByClassName("elegance-color-label")[0].innerHTML = "Black Midnight";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-capazo-stone")[0].style.display="none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-silla-stone")[0].style.display="none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-capazo-black")[0].style.display="block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-silla-black")[0].style.display="block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("circulo-stone")[0].classList.remove("highlighted-a");
        document.getElementsByClassName("circulo-stone-img")[0].classList.remove("highlighted-img");
        document.getElementsByClassName("circulo-black")[0].classList.add("highlighted-a");
        document.getElementsByClassName("circulo-black-img")[0].classList.add("highlighted-img");

                clickCheck('cochecito');
    }
}
```

Gracias :D

Comment: Pon todo el código, tambi;en el HTML y CSS.

Comment: aqui esta https://ghostbin.co/paste/uydug

Comment: Utiliza Stack Over Flow para añadir códigos, NO enlaces externos.